# discrete math (functions that include ceiling and floor

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

i know how to find if the given function is injective or subjective or
bijective, however when i get a function with cieling or floor i have no idea how to approch this. take these for example:
[image: functions with ceiling and floor examples]

i already have the final answer, however in the picture my prof. downloaded the font is too small even if i zoom you still can't see some steps. anyway this is my prof. [prof. solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QccZ5.png) solution for q 10 , how did he reach that 4 <= x <= 8?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I am guessing that you intended *surjective*, rather than *subjective*.  Consider the first problem, #10.  Since $~f(3) = 1 = f(4),~$ the function can't be injective.  Since it is a ceiling function, it is impossible (for example) for there to exist an $~x~$ such that $~f(x) = 1/2.~$ Therefore, the function can't be surjective.

Comment: Re previous comment, note that both the surjectivity and injectivity depend on the stated domain and range of the function.  Note further that in #10, you have that $~f ~: ~\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}.$

Comment: I hate this notation for a function

Comment: @Jakobian: Ha! Hate is a strong word, but the notation is certainly awkward. Being an amateur musician, I have often wondered if $x^\flat$ and $x^\sharp$ would do for floor and ceiling.

Comment: @TonyDean There is something similar in mathematics, [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

Answer (score 0):

Functions involving the floor and ceiling operators can be tricky. The best thing to do is graph the functions first. Such graphs should readily suggest whether they are injective and/or surjective and lead you to a proof.